# Height of TextView is greater than the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple layout with a `TextView` in it. I am trying to estimate its dimensions (height and width) at run-time. The code I use is as follows:

```
   Log.v(this.toString(), "Screen width = " + this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels + " and height = " + this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        Log.v(this.toString(), "TV width = " + tv.getWidth() + " and height = " + tv.getHeight());
        Log.v(this.toString(), "TV raw width = " + tv.getMeasuredWidth() + " and raw height = " + tv.getMeasuredHeight());
        Log.v(this.toString(), "TV width from display manager = " + getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() + " and height = " + getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
        tv.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        Log.v(this.toString(), "TV width from measurespec = " + tv.getMeasuredWidth() + " and height = " + tv.getMeasuredHeight());
        tv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //get view height and width here.
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Inside layout width and height measurer.");
                Log.v(this.toString(), "In layout listener, TV width = " + tv.getWidth() + " and height = " + tv.getHeight());
                tv.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                Log.v(this.toString(), "In layout listener, TV raw width = " + tv.getMeasuredWidth() + " and raw height = " + tv.getMeasuredHeight());
                Log.v(this.toString(), "TV width from display manager = " + getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() + " and height = " + getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
                if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    tv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
```

The phone I am testing it on is a `Samsung Galaxy S Duos`. In the `LogCat`, the height of the view is returned as 1058 pixels, which is greater than the phone's height of 800 pixels! The `LogCat` output is:

```
   01-12 12:35:38.749: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS@415f3ac8(18595): Screen width = 480 and height = 800
01-12 12:35:38.749: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS@415f3ac8(18595): TV width = 0 and height = 0
01-12 12:35:38.749: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS@415f3ac8(18595): TV raw width = 0 and raw height = 0
01-12 12:35:38.749: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS@415f3ac8(18595): TV width from display manager = 480 and height = 800
01-12 12:35:38.759: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS@415f3ac8(18595): TV width from measurespec = 48 and height = 32
01-12 12:35:38.929: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS$1@41068c38(18595): In layout listener, TV width = 480 and height = 1112
01-12 12:35:38.959: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS$1@41068c38(18595): In layout listener, TV raw width = 8518 and raw height = 59
01-12 12:35:38.959: V/com.sriram.hellotts.HelloTTS$1@41068c38(18595): TV width from display manager = 480 and height = 800
```

The layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelloTTS" >

         <!--  Footer aligned with the bottom -->
   <include
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout" 
        layout="@layout/footer_ehtv_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout" 
        layout="@layout/header_ehtv_layout" />

     <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/seekbar"
        android:text="@string/submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/submitText"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/submitText"
        android:text="Next Page" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previousPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/submitText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/submitText"
        android:text="Prev. Page" />

     <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/submitText"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My question(s):
1. How is this even possible?
2. What else can I do to ensure that the `TextView` height and width are returned correctly, that is, after the layout has been drawn.
Further, the `TextView` will only be displayed in portrait mode.

Comment: There's no reason a view can't be bigger than the screen. A TextView definitely will be if there's enough text in it and it's set to wrap content. Can you share your layout, either XML or your code if you set it up programmatically?

Comment: @Tenfour04: I have added the layout. To your point, once the view has been laid out, should the run-time value of the TextView not be less than the screen-size?

Comment: No, the size is whatever you set it to. That's why scroll views are needed...in case the size of its child view extends past the size of the screen.  In your case you are using "match_parent" for the height of a child view inside a vertically scrolling scroll view, which doesn't make practical sense and usually results in unexpected behavior. The TextView's height should be set to wrap_content. The same goes for the RelativeLayout that you're wrapping it in, although that seems to serve no purpose in this layout. You probably want to set `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView.

Comment: Actually, the ScrollView is also redundant--you could set the TextView height to match_parent and just omit the ScrollView and RelativeLayouts that are wrapping it, since TextViews already have built-in vertical scrolling.

Comment: I have posted some additional LogCat statements from what I tried and the measurements are becoming more and more weird. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this sample.

```
 Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int height=display.getHeight(); //you can get height
int weight=display.getWidth(); //you can get width


                  if(display.getHeight()==480&&display.getWidth()==320){

                  }

                  else if(display.getHeight()==800&&display.getWidth()==480){


                      }             
                  else if(display.getHeight()==320&&display.getWidth()==240){

                     }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Though these methods are deprecated since API 16 (I think), the size of the TextView is 480x800, which is the same as the phone screen. At run-time however, the size of the TextView is much smaller because other UI elements are also rendered. It is this dimension that I want.